# Network Interface Change Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, reachability, upnp

What is the best way to get notification while network interface becomes available/unavailable in iOS, **different from Reachability**? (maybe there is some good way of doing in SystemConfiguration or CFNetworks framework, or somehow using the native unix sockets networking API?)

Instead of checking network reachability I'm just checking if I'm able to get network info with this function, the only problem is when to check. I don't want to fire up an NSTimer every 0.1 second to do this, though it is solution, I would rather like to somehow get notified when user switches WiFi on/off in settings. (Reachability takes several seconds to nofity me when Im disabling wwan interface in settings.)

```
- (void)initializeCurrentNetworkInfo
{
    NSArray* interfacesSupported = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*) CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, interfacesSupported);
    NSDictionary* interfaceInfo = nil;

    for (NSString *interfaceName in interfacesSupported) {
        interfaceInfo = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)interfaceName);

        if (interfaceInfo && [interfaceInfo count]) {

            self.isInterfaceActive = YES;
            self.currentSSID = [NSString stringWithString:interfaceInfo[@"SSID"]];
            self.currentBSSID = [NSString stringWithString:interfaceInfo[@"BSSID"]];
            break;

        } else if (!interfaceInfo){
            self.isInterfaceActive = NO;

            self.currentBSSID = @"ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";;
            self.currentSSID = @"interface is unavailable";

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Info:** I'm developing the UPNP application, and each time interface becomes available/unavailable I subsequently initialise or nullify my UPNP service object. 
The problem is that in some rare occasions my app crashes, while I'm changing Wi-Fi switch on/off consequently for the purpose of testing. (Reachability works fine in the background)

So I could have traced it and found it that it obviously crashes while trying to receive an httpu datagram on socket of no longer available interface, when switching wifi off (`recvLen = cg_socket_recv(sock, dgmPkt);`), if I understand it right, it means that the background thread listening on socket in my UPNP framework (CyberGarages' CyberLink) is unaware of interface state changes(bug probably?), that's why I really want to stop the upnpService as fast as possible once the interface state changes.

I'm using the Tony Millions' Reachability version, and once I receive `networkReachabilityChanged:` I check for available interfaces, but I guess it's not the best way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, It's not duplicate. Please read it carefully, I'm already using Reachability. I'm not checking for internet connection, I want to somehow receive notification of enabled/disabled network interface - not checking internet reachability with google. Please edit it back again.

Comment: +1 but note that doing this just reduce the window where your app will crash following an interface change.  If you want your app to be robust, you'll also need to fix the underlying bug (or help the CyberLink maintainer to fix it)

Comment: Thanks for an advice. Already solved it.

Comment: @Hurden Any chance you could share your solution?

Comment: I can. What specifically are you referring to?